# Partition management strategy

Tags: azure-synapse

I am doing some PoC work with table partitioning in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  I have read the available documentation about table partitioning (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition) multiple times, but am having a bit of trouble coming up with a complete strategy to address my problem set, which seems like it would be common.

In my situation, I essentially want a partition for each unique value in the partition column - let's call it Date.  I am going to have new values coming in over time (requiring new partitions), and I am also going to need to replace the contents of one or more partitions multiple times per day while minimizing potential impact to users.  I have followed the section labeled "Table partitioning source control" as a strategy for initial partition setup.  I think that the need to replace some partitions multiple times per day means that I need to have an identical/empty staging table that I can purge/load and then use  partition swapping.  Some elements to the strategy that I feel I am missing are (I know there are several questions here - I am lumping them together incase there is some overarching aspect to this that I am missing):

- As I am processing data for new Date values, how would I check to see if I already have a partition for that value?  Just do a SPLIT RANGE and swallow the "boundary value being added is already present" error if it occurs?
- When loading the staging table, after I've confirmed that a partition for the Date that I am processing exists, I've heard that the most efficient thing to do to purge the partition is to DROP the partition (as opposed to delete...where date='') in order to avoid transaction logging...I see the documented syntax for this for SQL, but not SQL Data Warehouse?
- I see the syntax for swapping partitions - it seems to require that you know the partition number to be swapped.  How do you find out what partition number Date X is (I see some partition-related views, but can't quite put together how you get partion_number, given table name and value)?

Comment: I think I found an answer to the third bullet (finding partition number) under "optimizing with partition switching" here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-best-practices-transactions

Comment: On the second bullet, I had it in my head that the staging table would be long-lived, and I would need to purge the partition that I'm going to reload and swap in.  But I see (at the same article linked in my previous comment), that I can just create the staging table empty each time with the one partition that I'm going to swap in.